# ML classification algorithms give random profit

Tags: backtesting, python, machine-learning

I use `backtrader` `python` framework to backtest `ML` classification algorithms to make decision to buy or to sell.

When I use `RandomForest` or other algorithms in `scikit-learn` packages it gives up to 55% of profit:
[image: PROFIT]

The next run of absolutely **the same code and data** (just next run) gives 22% of loss:
[image: LOSS]

Why is that? And what are the methods to avoid such a big range of results? Less, but more stable profit is better :)

Comment: How can this be? Are you using random numbers (Monte Carlo) in your calculations?

Comment: No! Code is based on sklearn classification algorithms demo: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the random_state = 0 as a parameter in the model and retry this.

Comment: Yes, and then optimize the seed that works best for the range of markets. :D